# How powerful of a continuous wave laser do you need to create a laser induced plasma channel

Tags: laser, plasma-physics

I have been researching electro lasers. However I keep on finding resources of pulsed electro lasers however I have not found any resources on continuous wave electro lasers. So could continuous wave lasers exist wave lasers and if so what would their wattage be? From a human being.

Comment: Power is energy per unit time.  They use pulsed lasers because you can control the amount of power deposited into the system a little better by simply controlling the total energy output and duration of the laser pulse.  You can get extremely high wattage values of power input by simply reducing the duration of the pulse.  It also helps reduce the external influence of the laser on the plasma created by the initial input of energy.